# how to match relationships with multiple properties passed as a query parameter?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

let's say I have the following data model:

`(User)-[r:HAS_PERMISSIONS]->(n)` and the properties of 'r' are the permissions in boolean values, like view=true, create=true.

I want to find all the users that have certain permissions to an entity,
which are passed as query parameter.

naively I want something like:

`MATCH (u:User)-[r:HAS_PERMISSIONS {permissions}]->(n) RETURN u`,
which I know that isn't correct as `{permissions}` can only be used for the `CREATE` statement..

the passed permissions parameter is a map, something like `{view: true}`

I'm currently thinking of something like:

`MATCH (u:User)-[r:HAS_PERMISSIONS]->(n)
WHERE ALL(p in {permissions} WHERE r.{p} = {permissions}.p)
RETURN u`

obviously it won't work as permissions is a property map and not an array and I need to access it's keys and values somehow.

am I in the right direction ? how can I achieve what I'm looking for ?

Answer (score 1):

You can pass each of the properties of the `permissions` variable independently.

```
MATCH (u:User)-[r:HAS_PERMISSIONS { view: {view}, create: {create} }]->(n) RETURN u
```

Then pass in parameters `view` and `create`.

If you don't know what the permissions properties may be, you could handle it in the app. In Ruby, I'd do something like this:

```
def permissions_parameter(permissions)
  permission_keys   = []
  permission_values = []
  permissions.each do |k, v|
    permission_keys.push("r.#{k}: {#{k}}")
    permission_values.push("'#{k}': '#{v}'")
  end
  permission_keys_cypher = permission_keys.join(', ')
  permission_params_cypher = permission_values.join(', ')
  [permission_keys_cypher, permission_params_cypher]
end

permissions = permissions_parameter({ create: true, view: true })
puts "MATCH (u:User)-[r:HAS_PERMISSIONS { #{permissions[0]} }]->(n) RETURN u"
# MATCH (u:User)-[r:HAS_PERMISSIONS { r.create: {create}, r.view: {view} }]->(n) RETURN u
puts "params: #{permissions[1]}"
# params: 'create': 'true', 'view': 'true'
```

Comment: what if I don't know the set of available permissions beforehand ?

Comment: That's another story. ;-) If you're able to put the permissions into the parameter, it must exist in your app somewhere before going to the server. Can you handle that in your app?

Comment: I'm looking into writing a general query, which won't have to be changed if new permissions are added in the future, one that simply matches all the permissions given as a parameter

Comment: If you're passing the params in a hash like `{create: true}`, you can still handle it in the app. I modified my answer with an example of how you could handle it using Ruby to demonstrate, but you can use the same idea in whichever language you're using. Just create a method/function that turns the permissions hash into something appropriate for cypher.

Comment: If one exists, I'd love to see it!